# How to configure PHP and nginx to display errors only for specific IP addresses?

Tags: php, nginx

How do I configure PHP and nginx to display errors only for specific IP addresses?

Comment: Why not to log everything instead? Displaying errors is never a good idea on production servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first set PHP to not display errors at all (`display_errors = Off` in `php.ini`), then use the `auto_prepend_file` directive in your php.ini to include this script:

```
<?php
$allowed_ips = array('111.111.111.111', ...);
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowed_ips)) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
```

Comment: Some sort of errors like Fatal still wouldn't be visible for that ip

Comment: Yes, it's true. Though I wonder, since this would be the very first thing that runs, only parse errors and static includes not found would remain invisible. Would you agree? I don't actually know the PHP execution lifecycle that well.

Comment: I'd agree, yes, but I still think that this is not acceptable for production

Comment: I'm with you on that, though sometimes you do find heisenbugs that only appear in production. Logging is indeed the answer.

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea: I have left comments, doesn't worth separated answer ;-)